# Pyomo-How to calculate the factorial of numbers？

Tags: python, factorial, pyomo

I am trying to use a function in my objective function. like this:

```
qn = pow(a, m.x[1]) / factorial(m.x[1])
qh = pow(b, m.x[2]) / factorial(m.x[2])
qn_1 = pow(c, m.x[3]) / factorial(m.x[3])
qh_1 = pow(d, m.x[4]) / factorial(m.x[4])
qn_2 = pow(e, m.x[5]) / factorial(m.x[5])

G = G + qn + qh + qh_1 + qn_1 + qn_2

m.obj = Objective(expr=G, sense=minimize)
```

But when I try to call this function in my objective function above, I get the message below :

```
pyomo.common.errors.PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (x[1]  ==  0) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container membership or equality. For example,
    >>> m.x = Var()
    >>> if m.x >= 1:
    ...     pass
and
    >>> m.y = Var()
    >>> if m.y in [m.x, m.y]:
    ...     pass
would both cause this exception.
```

The factorial function like this:

```
def factorial(num):
    if num == 1 or num == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return num * factorial(num - 1)
```

I don't know how to correct it. I used some other methods of factorial, but none of them worked.
How can I solve this?

Comment: # I modified the Factorial function like this:
    def f(n):
        total = 1
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            total *= i
        return total
# I got the following mistakes:
#TypeError: 'SumExpression' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: # I modified the Factorial function like this
    def f(n):
        total = 1
        total = reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, (i+1 for i in range(n)))
        return total
    # I got the following mistakes:
    # TypeError: '_GeneralVarData' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: The problem isn't your factorial function....  It is that you are trying to pass non-linear expressions into your model.  Realize that `pyomo` is just constructing linear (and nonlinear) expressions and handing them to a solver.  It cannot pass in a function reference.  So, let's talk options.  Are the possible options for x[i] bounded in some reasonable way?